# How do I use django-treebeard to build a sitemap?

Tags: python, django, django-treebeard

I have setup a django-treebeard model that has child nodes and what not. How do I now display this in my template? This is what I have so far.

My Models:

```
class SiteMapEntry(MP_Node):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=False, blank=False)

    node_order_by = ['name']

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Sitemap Entry"
        verbose_name_plural = "Sitemap Entries"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return ('%s - %s' % (self.name, self.url))
```

My Views:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
    class SiteMap(ListView):
        model = SiteMapEntry
        template_name = 'sitemaps.html'
```

My Template:

```
{% block content %}
    <h1>Sitemap</h1>

    <br /><br />

    {% for url in object_list %}
<p>{{ url.name }}</p>
<p>{{ url.url }}</p>
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock content %}
```

What this is doing right now, obviously is just listing the nodes and its children without any indenting. How do I list it like a tree in my template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `get_annotated_list` node method to get a data structure you can iterate on in the template:

http://django-treebeard.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#treebeard.models.Node.get_annotated_list

There's also an example there that shows you exactly how to do it:

```
{% for item, info in annotated_list %}
    {% if info.open %}
        <ul><li>
    {% else %}
        </li><li>
    {% endif %}    

    {{ item }}    

    {% for close in info.close %}
        </li></ul>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Have a look at the `dump_bulk` method which returns a nested data structure too:

http://django-treebeard.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#treebeard.models.Node.dump_bulk

Hope it's helpful.